# BibLaTex cite style: prenote [number] postnote

Tags: biblatex, citing

I would like to see this output for `\cite[see][1]{Key}`, e.g.: "see [2], p. 1". That means like `style=numeric`, but only the number should be wrapped in square brackets, but not the rest.

More general: "prenote [number] postnote"

I could not find any cite style, that does something similar.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You can [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do ***not*** know what I am doing ;).

## *Caveat emptor...*

---

This code attempts to define a new citation command, `\textualcite[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key list>}` which produces the target output. Since you didn't post any code, I have no idea if this will work with your actual bibliography style, document class and usage; whether your cat will leave home in protest; or how long your pizza will take to be delivered. That is, *your kilometres may, and almost certainly will, vary....*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\newbibmacro*{textualcite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textualcite}%[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}%
    {}%
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}\addspace}%
    \bibopenbracket\setunit{}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textualcite}}%
  {\multicitedelim}%
  {\bibclosebracket%
    \usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}

  \cite{aristotle:anima}
  \cites[see][1]{aristotle:rhetoric,aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics}

  \textcite[see][1]{aristotle:poetics}

  \textcites[see][1]{aristotle:rhetoric,aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics}

  \textualcite[see][1]{aristotle:rhetoric}

  \textualcite[see][]{aristotle:anima}

  \textualcite[1]{aristotle:poetics}

  \textualcite[see][1]{aristotle:rhetoric,aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics}

  \textualcite[see][]{aristotle:rhetoric,aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics}

  \textualcite[1]{aristotle:rhetoric,aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics}

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: citing, text citing and textual citing]

But don't say I didn't warn you...

[image: mae'r gath yn gadael ei chartref]

Comment: You do put on quite a show, don't you `;-)`. The cat looks at the same time cute and creepy ...

Comment: @moewe Egregious here, of course. But I couldn't resist. I have a TikZ library for drawing cats and another for drawing trams/trolleys/buses. (I just call it a bus if I want a bus rather than a tram.) Though they seem to be at very different scales so I had to scale the bus up by a factor of 50.